# C# datadriven test using multiple files as datasource

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am writing a data driven unit test and there are a lot of test cases and it would be easier to maintain if they could be separated in multiple xml files.

Is it possible to have a datadriven test use every file in a directory as the datasource?

Or can I combine all files into one before the test starts and use that as the datasource?